# Hidden Characters using subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, variables, subprocess, popen

I am trying to get a numeric value from the following code.  When I "print" out the value I get a number "1".  Yet when it goes to the "if" statement I always get "closed" as the stored variable in "STORE".  The third line of the code is used to remove the carriage return.

```
CLOSED = subprocess.Popen(
    [
        "ssh",
        "hostname",
        "/usr/blaine/store_status | grep 00 | awk \{\'print $5\'\}"
    ],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE
)



CLOSED_OUTPUT = CLOSED.stdout.read()
CLOSED_OUTPUT = CLOSED_OUTPUT.replace('\n','')
```

(Having a hard time getting the if statement to show properly, I do have proper indentions and it does work if I assign the variable)

```
if CLOSED_OUTPUT == 1:
    STORE = "open"
else:
    STORE = "closed"

print ("The store is %s." % (STORE))
```

Answer (score 2):

CLOSED_OUTPUT is a string, so it will never compare equal to the integer 1.

You could try

```
if CLOSED_OUTPUT == '1':
```

or, if you expect that the result is usually an integer, convert it to an integer before using it.

Answer (score 0):

```
from subprocess import check_output

output = check_output(["ssh", "hostname",
    "/usr/blaine/store_status | grep 00 | awk \{'print $5'\}"])
try:
    value = int(output)
except ValueError:
    opened = False
else:
    opened = (value == 1)

print("The store is {}.".format("open" if opened else "closed"))
```

`int()` ignores whitespace such as `'\n'` i.e., you don't need to do the replacement. You could also reimplement `grep .. | awk` part in Python. `paramiko` (Python ssh library) allows you to run a remote command via ssh without running `ssh` subprocess.